# Curve function in r with expr different from x

Tags: r, curve

I have found few codes on line but non of them could help me solve my problem. I know the expr needs x but I couldn't find way to plot these to functions using the curve function. I am able to plot them when the model has only one independent variable but not more than one. Here is the code

```
n <- 50
x1 <- runif(n = n, min = 0, max = 1)   
x2 <- rnorm(n,mean = -50,1)
x3 <- rnorm(n=n,mean =50,sd=8)         
z <- 3 - 4.2*x1 - x2 - x3            
pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))                  
y <- rbinom(n=n,1,pr)
y
# create dataframe
df = data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2,x3=x3)

m <- glm( y~.,data=df,family=binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(m)
beta.hat <- m$coefficients
z.hat <- beta.hat[1] + beta.hat[2]*x1 + beta.hat[3]*x2 + beta.hat[4]*x3

curve(expr = exp(z) / (1 + exp(z)), xlim = c(0,1), ylab = expression(pi), n = 1000, lwd = 3, xlab = expression(z/hat(z)))
curve(expr = exp(z.hat)/(1 + exp(z.hat)), xlim = c(0,1), add = TRUE, col = "red", n = 1000)
```

Comment: The curve plot will depict relation between P(y|z) and z. You need to specify range for z, not how the z values were computed. One z value might have different combinations of x1,x2 and x3.

Comment: @Lstat what do you mean, could you please be more specific, I have thought about this but I don't know how to fix it. Can you help please to generic?

Comment: @Stat I think the problem is in design rather than with `curve` function. You cannot visualise two steps at once: relation between z~x and P(y)~z. z~x is a multivariate problem,

Comment: @Lstat when I change the code to  curve(expr = exp(z) / (1 + exp(z)), from=min(z),to=max(z), ylab = expression(pi), n = 1000, lwd = 3, xlab = expression(z/hat(z)))
curve(expr = exp(z.hat)/(1 + exp(z.hat)), from=min(z.hat), to = max(z.hat), add = TRUE, col = "red", n = 1000), it works now but I am not sure if this is right

Comment: I cannot run your plots. Let's try this: define sigmoid function as: `functionZ <- function(Z){(exp(Z)) / (1+exp(Z)) }`. Include this into: `curve(expr = functionZ, from=min(z),to=max(z)) `.